# Ошибка с кодировкой ТЕКСТА

Tags: java, oracle, spring-mvc, кодировка

Делаю `HTTP` запрос, из `ORACLE`,посылаю `JSON` на `Spring-MVC`.Метод в контроллере `Spring-MVC` принимает `JSON`.Если из `ORACLE` в теле `JSON`-а добавляю только латинские буквы то все хорошо отрабатывает а если там кириллица то `Spring-MVC` выдает `400 Bad Request`.В логах `Tomcat`-a пишет что не может распарсить `JSON` из-за кодировки.Помогите кто чем сможет..

**PLSQL**

```
content := '{"to":"996707332572","from":"Имя отправителя","text":"Текст смс"}';

dbms_output.put_line(content);
req := utl_http.begin_request(url, 'POST',' HTTP/1.1');
utl_http.set_header(req, 'user-agent', 'mozilla/4.0'); 
utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Type', 'application/json');
utl_http.set_header(req, 'Accept', 'application/xml');
utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Length', length(content));
utl_http.set_body_charset ('UTF-8');
utl_http.write_text(req, content);

res := utl_http.get_response(req);
```

**Controller**

```
    @ResponseBody
    @PostMapping(value = "/send-msg",
            produces = "application/xml; charset=utf-8",consumes = "application/json")
    public Object sendMsgGet(@RequestBody SmsBody smsBody) throws Exception {
```

**Класс SmsBody**

```
public class SmsBody {
    private String to;
    private String from;
    private String text;
    /*
      get/set...
     */
```

**POM.xml**

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.13</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

**WEB.xml**

```
<web-app version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.gif</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jpeg</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.png</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.mp4</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>characterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена, в `PLSQL` запросе увеличил `Content-Length`

```
utl_http.set_header(req, 'Content-Length', length(content)+10);
```